# How can I find all affected projects via `nx`?

Tags: typescript, github, github-actions, cicd, monorepo

I am using `nx` to manage a mono repo for typescript projects. I know `nx` has a command `affected` which can be used to only on the changed project and other projects that depends on it. It is a nice feature for compiling. But I also need my CICD pipeline works the same way.

I am using github and gitaction. I'd like to trigger the pipeline only for the impacted projects.

As an example, I have below folder structure in github, it has 3 projects and 1 library. The `proj1` and `proj2` depends on `pdfgenerator` library. How can I only trigger the CICD pipeline for `proj1` and `proj2` when I change `pdfgenerator`?

```
projects/proj1
projects/proj2
projects/proj3
libraries/pdfgenerator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set up a CI/CD pipeline using GitHub Actions that only triggers workflows for projects affected by changes, you can leverage [Nx's affected commands](https://nx.dev/concepts/affected), which are designed to help you run commands only on projects which are affected by recent changes.
See [`nx show projects --affected`](https://nx.dev/packages/nx/documents/show)

```bash
nx show projects --affected --base=main --head=HEAD
```

Set up a GitHub Action workflow in your repository. Create a new YAML file under the `.github/workflows` directory.

Make sure that you fetch the necessary base branch to properly compare the changes.
In the job steps, add a step to fetch the base branch (assuming 'main' is your base branch):

```yaml
- name: Fetch Base Branch
    run: |
    git fetch origin main:main
```

Identify the affected projects using the Nx CLI. Use a step to run the Nx affected command and store the output into an environment variable:

```yaml
- name: Identify affected projects
  run: |
    echo "AFFECTED=$(nx show projects --affected --json --base=main --head=HEAD | jq -r '.projects | join(" ")')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

In the `build` job, you can use a [matrix strategy](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs) to run a separate build for each project (`proj1`, `proj2`, `proj3`).
The `if` condition checks if the project name is contained in the list of affected projects before running the build command. If the project is affected, the build command runs; otherwise, it is skipped.

```yaml
  build:
    needs: identify_affected
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        project: [proj1, proj2, proj3]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build Project
        if: contains(needs.identify_affected.outputs.affected, matrix.project)
        run: nx build ${{ matrix.project }}
```

Full script:

```yaml
name: Build Affected Projects

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  identify_affected:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      affected: ${{ steps.set-output.outputs.affected }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Fetch Base Branch
        run: |
          git fetch origin main:main

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install -g nx

      - name: Identify affected projects
        run: |
          echo "AFFECTED=$(nx show projects --affected --json --base=main --head=HEAD | jq -r '.projects | join(" ")')" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Set affected projects as output
        id: set-output
        run: echo "::set-output name=affected::${{ env.AFFECTED }}"

  build:
    needs: identify_affected
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        project: [proj1, proj2, proj3]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build Project
        if: contains(needs.identify_affected.outputs.affected, matrix.project)
        run: nx build ${{ matrix.project }}
```

Nx is installed globally in the GitHub Actions runner to ensure the `nx` command is available.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination. Can you explain what apps mean in `affected:apps`? I don't have this target in the project.

Comment: Should I use `nx affected:proj1 --base=main --head=HEAD --plain`? It gives me an error `Error: Both project and target have to be specified`

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao You are correct, this would not be supported. I have amended the answer to use [`nx print-affected`] instead.

Comment: Thanks. I found `print-affected` is deprecated. I make it work by using `nx show projects`.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Good point. I have edited the answer to use that command.